# Update with axios put do not work on API / React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-webapi, rest

I'm new to react and rest Apis to start with, but hope i can get a hint or tip on this one..

Im trying to do a update function on my own API buildt in ASP.Net Core, but i getting "PUT http://localhost:33255/api/Cities/9 400 (Bad Request)" error... I think my ID not get passed?

The values im trying to send

```
state = {
  Cities: [],
    editCitiesData: {
    citiesId: '',
    cityName: '',
    cipCode: '',
    countryName: ''
  },
  editCitiesModal: false
}
```

my function:

```
updateCities(){

  let {cityName, zipCode, countryName } = this.state.editCitiesData;


  axios.put('http://localhost:33255/api/Cities/' + this.state.editCitiesData.citiesId, {
    cityName, zipCode, countryName
  }).then((response) => {
    this._refreshCities();
    console.log(response.data);
  })
}
```

And my onClick:

```
<Button color="primary" onClick={this.updateCities.bind(this)}>Update city</Button>{' '}
```

Thankful for help!

Edit
////

A breakpoint on my api showed this:
[Return 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/974wT.png)

Comment: Is your `this.state.editCitiesData.citiesId` an empty string right? Like you defined in the state. Try first adding by hand an id to your state, so this way you can research if there is any problem with the frontend or with the backend. Also recommendable using Postman, check this out: https://www.postman.com/

Comment: Yes it's a empty string. I checked how the request looked like in my Api and updated my question with a picture. When im using postman i can successfully update but i get this Status: 204 no content. Is my api broken for put methods?

Comment: PUT verb means that you will replace a row info. Is the frontend fetch id in your database? Seems that you are trying to Put something that does not exists!

Comment: Yes exactly. My id does not show in the request payload when im looking at Headers... How do i send the id correctly in the function? feels like i tried everything. I also get this "PUT localhost:33255/api/Cities/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)" now..

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the button a value, so when you call the updateCities function is passed and received to do the query:

```
<Button value={city.id} color="primary" onClick={this.updateCities.bind(this)}>Update city</Button>
```

Now, in the updateCities function receive the id:

```
updateCities({currentTarget}){
  const id = currentTarget.value //here you define the id of the city to update

  let {cityName, zipCode, countryName } = this.state.editCitiesData;


  axios.put('http://localhost:33255/api/Cities/' + id, { //here you pass that id
    cityName, zipCode, countryName
  }).then((response) => {
    this._refreshCities();
    console.log(response.data);
  })
}
```

Comment: Think i understand but getting this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" now?

Comment: If it's undefined, it means you don't have that value yet. I think you need to get the id of the city first so you can pass it on to the function. Otherwise you are not doing things properly. First things first. Make a call to get all cities, using componentDidMount() and set the response in the state (Cities) which is an array. Then use map to go through all the cities and render each city with a button which contains the id you need to pass to the function, so you can finally call the function to update the data in the database. Hope this helps get things cleared up.